# Limit Google map search to shipping ports

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to limit Google map search only to shipping ports. There are [multiple type of places](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) but It does not suggest PORT type.

So far I found [this website](https://www.shipafreight.com/) which only searches within cities having PORTs but I can not find the algorithm as it is a full JavaScript website with ugly codes.

Comment: Where do you really ask programmin questions about `google maps-api-3` configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Places API doesn't support type `port` or `seaport` at the moment. There is a feature request in the Google issue tracker to add these types, you can see it here

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110475636

As you can see this request was created on June 20, 2018 and wasn't resolved yet. Please feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.

Comment: Do you guess how the sample website I mentioned works? Is it a prepared database?